# how do I launch a chrome app from a web page?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I hope i can do something like

```
chrome://<magic-invoke>?param1=42&param2=woohoo
```

I tried doing a content script and setting up a function that a page could call, but content scripts aren't allowed in apps (and I want an app cos I need sockets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable for details on a method that should do what you want.

Note for this to work your app needs to declare which pages can connect to it.

Comment: it would be nice if you could launch one via url directly. But seems u cannot